# ANT Migration to add namespace to packaging org?

Tags: ant, migration-tool, jenkins

I have two dev org one where I did code and other is packaging org where I have to create a managed package.

How can I configure ANT tool with `build.xml` and `build.properties` files to add the namespace to the packaging org?

For moving code I am using jenkins with ANT tool in AWS.

**Edit:**

I contacted Salesforce team and they say that in lightning components each js where you calling your apex class you need to change manually. Not sure that is correct way or not.

Answer (score 2):

This happens automatically. There's typically no need to do anything special in your build.properties or build.xml files, or any special configuration you need to do, unless you are also managing the [package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_package.htm) file as well, in which case you'll need to update the fullName and namespacePrefix values in your package.xml file.

Comment: We have some question about Namespace. We build Managed Packages to make our software available and these packages are identified by a Salesforce Namespace which is unique to the packaging org for our application, however, we do development in separate Org and the orgs we use for development did not have a namespace defined. So could you tell us how we use/handle dynamic Namesapce while developing the App

Below is the development cycle we follow: 

dev org -> (move code using Jenkins) -> testing org  (move code using Jenkins) -> packaging org

Comment: @JayminSuthar Again, you generally don't need to worry about. And if it's something that *is* a problem, you need to be using Salesforce DX.

Comment: You right but here's a scenario what I have: I build managed package and install in testing dev org, Namespace it brings it up but in lighting component js I need to change as manually.

I opened a ticket with Salesforce team and they say: `If you want to package the lightning components and use in other org, you should use the namespace prefix instead of 'c'.`
Example: `<aura:dependency resource="<NameSpace>:HelloGeek"/>`

Do you have an idea how I can overcome it?

Comment: @JayminSuthar There may yet be bugs with the deployment process (I wasn't aware of this limitation). Still, have you looked into using DX? It's designed to address this problem directly.